# waiting socket server response with java client

Tags: java, sockets, response

This client has to interact with a private server.
I have to do this:

1. send from client a block message "Block"
2. request some xml data via persistent tcp
3. send from client an unlock message "Unlock"

The problem is that when I send command for receive the xml data, the shell remains stationary to the line `readLine()` and anything is returned.

This is my Client code:

```
            /* LOCK  */
            socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 7000);
            socket.setSoTimeout(50000);
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            System.out.println("\nlocking...");
            out.write(lockCommand);

            out.flush();
            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();

            /* SEND BOLLE COMMAND  */
            //String command = "OBolle                                   01/05/2015\ff";
            byte[] bolleCommand= {0x4f, 0x42, 0x6f, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x30, 0x31, 0x2f, 0x30, 0x35, 0x2f , 0x32, 0x30, 0x31, 0x35, (byte) 0xff};              
            socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 7001);
            socket.setSoTimeout(50000);
            out = socket.getOutputStream();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            System.out.println("\nsending command for receive XML data.....");
            out.write(bolleCommand);

            System.out.println("\nReading XML response.....");
            String response = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("in "+ response);

            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();

            /* UNLOCK  */
            socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 7000);
            socket.setSoTimeout(50000);
            out = socket.getOutputStream();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            System.out.println("\nunlocking...");
            out.write(unlockCommand);
            out.flush();

            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();

            System.out.println("\nAll done...");
```

I have to wait the server response, that is returned after 10/15 seconds.

The connection is TCP Persistent.

I try also:

```
//String response = in.readLine();
            //System.out.println("in "+ response);
            int dataBuffer;
            while ((dataBuffer = socket.getInputStream().read()) != -1) 
               System.out.print((char)dataBuffer);
```

But I have the some result...
How can I do?

Thank you so much.

This is an example of returned data:

```
<DocumentElement>\r\n  <ValoreTesto1 />\r\n    <ValoreTesto2 />\r\n    <ValoreTesto3 />\r\n    <ValoreTesto4 />\r\n    <ValoreTesto5 />\r\n    <ValoreTesto6 />\r\n    <ValoreTesto7 />\r\n    <ValoreTesto8 />\r\n    <ValoreTesto9 />\r\n        <QData>2015-05-09T00:00:00+02:00</QData>\r\n
```

UPDATE:
with an accurate sniffing I understand that the server work in this mode:

send lock command to 7000
send retrieve command data on 7001
send unlock to 7000
retrieve the data from command 2

Comment: out.flush() after out.write().

Comment: anything chainging @zubergu

Comment: @michele Hi, just want to make sure, does the data contain line terminator?

Comment: Hi @kucing_terbang, data returned terminate with \r\n. I see this with a packet sniffer.

Comment: The result of `InputStream.read()` with no parameters is a byte, not a `dataBuffer.`

Comment: @EJP: No InputStream returns a byte as int so that part is correct. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html

Comment: @michele If you telnet to the server:port do you have to send something before the server starts sending the XML file? If yes what do you have to send?

Comment: @michele hmm.. so, based on your update, then, how did you get the xml data? it might because of that as the `readline()` function is waiting for either `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`

Comment: @gfelisberto I have add the screenshot about Socket Sniffer, that show you the packets that are transimtted when I send Bolle (command in java code).

Comment: @gfelisberto I have add the screenshot about Socket Sniffer, that show you the packets that are transimtted when I send Bolle (command in java code).

Comment: @gfelisberto It doesn't return a buffer. There is nothing correct about calling an int or a byte a buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the input stream from the socket:

```
BufferedReader in =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String fromServer = in.readLine();
```

You can get extra help by reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Comment: not working, see my edited answer. Thanks

Comment: in.readLine() will read a single line from the server. You need to assign it to a variable and use it.
Also in your first example you were sending to the server and then waiting for a reply. Now it seems you want to connect to the server, read some messages and then send something to the server.

Comment: already not working, I try the message with PacketSender tool and it's correct.
I have to send the command and wait for an xml from server.

Comment: Answer edited with more info

Comment: My answer is correct for you original problem. You were no properly reading from the socket.

Answer (score 0):

```
String command = "OBolle                                   01/05/2015\ff";
out.write(command.getBytes());
```

Usual problem. You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. Add a line terminator, or use `println().`

Comment: sorry what I have to change?

Comment: @michele What part of 'add a line terminator, or use `println()`' don't you understand?

Comment: I tried String command = "OBolle                                   01/05/2015\ff\r\n"
but is not working

Comment: In second option I don't understand about println ... Do you mean out.println(...)?? But it's not correct.
Thanks

Comment: You also have to do it with `lockCommand` and anything else you send. You should also be doing all this over a single socket, not opening/closing a socket per command. When I suggest you could use `println()` I mean the method that is exported by a couple of JDK classes that you can easily look up for yourself and determine how to use. I expect that.

Comment: but lockCommand and unlockCommand are in port 7000
The second command on 7001.

Comment: Server requires that first I have to send lockCommand on 7000, after commandBolle on 7001 and after unlockCommand on 7000

Comment: Is that relevant? Does the server not expect to read lines on both ports? What *is* the server? Where is its code? What is its protocol? You can't seriously expect a full solution when you only provide half the information.

Comment: I have no code for Server, I have specified it. It work via TCP. thanks anyway

Comment: You haven't specified the protocol. The issue here is whether the server reads lines or not.